# adding removing classes for checkbox and drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am adding and removing class to the elements on change event. The below code is working for dropdown and radio buttons, but is not working for checkbox and dropdown. The disable class gets applied, but on unchecking it is not getting enabled..

```
$(function() {
  $switchers.each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).prop("disabled", false).removeClass("c_disabled")
        .closest(".wrapper")
        .find(".overlay").remove();

    if ($(elem).prop('tagName') == 'SELECT') {          
        $(elem).children().removeClass('dis').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
```

How can I make it work for checkbox's check, uncheck.

For example, If you see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surajshukla/psp3j12q/2/) when you check **C3**, dropdown option **Two** gets disabled, but when you uncheck it, it doesn't get enabled again, It gets enable while you uncheck other checked checkbox.

What is the reason for this? When I have a combination of radio and dropdown it works for that.

I want it to enable it once I uncheck **C3**

It has anything to do with the point of checkbox being multiselect?

I am able to check If the options are checked or unchecked with the below code.

```
    $(".checkdrop").on("change", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
      var ischecked = e.target.checked;
      if(ischecked) {
        alert("checked it");

      }
      else
      {
        alert("unchecked it");

       //$(elem).removeClass('c_disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
      } 
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surajshukla/psp3j12q/2/)

Please help.

Comment: `The below code is working for dropdown and radio buttons, but is not working for checkbox and dropdown`. Is it working for `dropdown` or not?

Comment: so when certain dropdown option is getting disabled for radio options, then on check and uncheck it is getting enabled. (We check the radio options but there's nothing called uncheck) whereas we can check uncheck for checkbox.

hope I am able to explain the case

Answer (score 0):

These lines are working on their own. You may check it on the console.

```
 $(".c_disabled").prop("disabled",false);
 $(".c_disabled").removeClass("c_disabled");
```

Comment: sure, Thanks. Any idea on the issue?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it and apply to your code in your way.

Comment: are you sure this is working? Not working for me? Can you put this in the fiddle and see?

Comment: Not working there. When you click C3, It disables Two, but on uncheck doesn't enable it back. that's what I want to achieve

Comment: Oh sorry, Updated my response again. I have tested on the console it works. Your problem might be the algorithm.

Comment: it is not doing the thing I want.